# HBase 1.0 Filter issue

Tags: hbase

I am using java code for fetching data from HBase. I am using the filter as follows:

Say value is `"1"` and I converted it into byte array `valueInBytes`

```
 SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("cf_name"),
                Bytes.toBytes("FOLLOWER_ID"), CompareOp.EQUAL, valueInBytes);


ROW                                COLUMN+CELL                                                                                        
 1                                 column=cf_name:USER_NAME, timestamp=1439264252424, value=aaa                                     
 2                                 column=cf_name:FOLLOWER_ID, timestamp=1439264252437, value=1                                       
 2                                 column=cf_name:USER_NAME, timestamp=1439264252437, value=bbb                                       
 3                                 column=cf_name:FOLLOWER_ID, timestamp=1439264252444, value=2                                       
 3                                 column=cf_name:USER_NAME, timestamp=1439264252444, value=ccc
```

Along with ROW 2, it's fetching ROW 1 also as there is no field `FOLLOWER_ID`. How to remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I need to set the property.

```
filter.setFilterIfMissing(true);
```